# Returning index and item in a function definition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to get following result within a function definition. When I use a `for` loop it works perfectly but when I use `def` it only gives me the first item.

```
text= "I am not a student, but I like to be "
text1= text.split()

for index,item in enumerate(text1):
    print (index, item)
```

Output:

```
0 I
1 am
2 not
3 a
4 student,
5 but
6 I
7 like
8 to
9 be
```

However, this does not work within a function `def`. Could you help me to get the result within one?

```
text= "I am not a student,but I like to be "
text1= text.split()

def words(text):
    for index,item in enumerate(text1):
        return index, item

words(text1)
```

Output:

```
(0, 'I')
```

Comment: because you are returning the first item , you should do `return list(enumerate(text1))`

Answer (score 2):

The `return` exits the function and interrupts what it was doing in the function, never to be finished.

If you don't return the first values, but print all of them like you do in the first example, you will see the same output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `return` in the function ends its execution during the first iteration of the `for` loop. So, to do the same things as the non-function version, you'd need to `print()` each pair of value *inside* of it, as shown below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def words(text):
    for index,item in enumerate(text1):
        print(index, item)

text1 = "I am not a student, but I like to be ".split()

words(text1)
```

Output:

```
0 I
1 am
2 not
3 a
4 student,
5 but
6 I
7 like
8 to
9 be
```